# PHP color of the first line in a loop

Tags: php, html, css

Im trying to read a txt file and show the content via PHP. Loading it and displaying it is working fine. I would like the different words to have a different color. But the first line never gets the correct color.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<?php
$fontcolor=Black;
$row = 1;

echo "<TABLE width=100%>";
echo "<TD>";
### State section
if (($handle = fopen("sdmon12images\State.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($data[$c] == "Busy"):
                $fontcolor=Red;
            endif;
            if ($data[$c] == "Pause"):
                $fontcolor=Blue;
            endif;
            if ($data[$c] == "Idle"):
                $fontcolor=Green;
            endif;
            if ($data[$c] == "Post processing"):
                $fontcolor=Orange;
            endif;          
            echo "<font color=$fontcolor>" . $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $fontcolor=Black;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo "</TD>";
echo "</TABLE>";
?>
</HTML>
```

The result is that the first line is standard color and the other lines are colored correctly. How do i get the first line colored in the correct color?

Comment: Could you show us the first lines of the TXT file ? Also, there are many errors in your HTML code.

Comment: Improve your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<?php
$fontcolor="Black";
$row = 1;

echo "<table width='100%'>";
echo "<td>";
### State section
if (($handle = fopen("sdmon12images\State.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($data[$c] == "Busy"):
                $fontcolor="Red";
            endif;
            if ($data[$c] == "Pause"):
                $fontcolor="Blue";
            endif;
            if ($data[$c] == "Idle"):
                $fontcolor="Green";
            endif;
            if ($data[$c] == "Post processing"):
                $fontcolor="Orange";
            endif;          
            echo "<font color='$fontcolor'>" . $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $fontcolor="Black";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```